# Перенести иконки меню на правую сторону в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

Добрый день. У меня такой вопрос:
По умолчанию, когда открываешь Menu Navigation drawer там иконки слева, а текст справа
(иконка заголовок)
Я хочу поменять их местами, т.е 
(заголовок иконка)
Как можно это делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У элемента `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` в файле разметки установите следующее свойство:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

**UPD#1** это работает начиная с ***API Level 17***. Чтобы работало на более ранних версиях API можно использовать `ViewCompat` из `android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat` библиотеки.

```
ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection (View yourView, int layoutDirection) // где layoutDirection - это ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Можно еще вопрос? а можно как нибудь так сделать чтоб половина остались по умолчанию (иконка заголовок)
а другая половина (заголовок иконка)?

Comment: @androidx можно, вам надо сделать кастомный Navigation Drawer